# Execute curl command within Python

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, bottle

I am a beginner with python. I am trying to execute a curl command within Python script.

If I do it in the terminal, it looks like this:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "hawkular-tenant: test" -X GET https://www.example.com/test | python -m json.tool
```

I tried to do research, so I think I can use urllib2 library.

How can I run this command?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a `cURL` to Python `requests` conversion service. http://curl.trillworks.com/ is though.

Comment: Is there a reason you have you use `curl`, rather than just sending HTTP requests from inside Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
import subprocess

bash_com = 'curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "hawkular-tenant: test" -X GET https://www.example.com/test | python -m json.tool'
subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bash_com])
```

This is a good way of doing this because it avoids using `os.system` which can make things ugly. But try to avoid calling bash commands from inside Python, specially in a case like this where you could simply use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subprocess with Popen and communicate to execute commands and retrieve the output.

```
def executeCommand(cmd, debug = False):
   '''
   Excecute a command and return the stdiout and errors.
   cmd: list of the command. e.g.: ['ls', '-la']
   '''
   try:
      cmd_data = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      output,error = cmd_data.communicate()
      if debug:
         if (len(error)>1):
            print 'Error:', error
         if (len(output)>1):
            print 'Output:', output
      return output, error
   except:
      return 'Error in command:', cmd
```

Then, you put your command as

```
executeCommand(['curl', '-k', '-H', '"Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"', '-H', '"hawkular-tenant: test"', '-X', 'GET', 'https://www.example.com/test', '|', 'python', '-m', 'json.tool'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend calling `curl` via your shell from inside Python. What about `httplib`?

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("https://www.example.com/test")
conn.request("HEAD","Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
conn.request("HEAD", "hawkular-tenant: test")
res = conn.getresponse()
```

If you're using Python3 then you'll need to swap `httplib` for `http.client`

Comment: [File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 732, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//hawkularmetrics.apps.10.2.2.2.xip.io/hawkular/metrics/metrics']
I am getting this issue now.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `pycurl` library.

```
pip install pycurl
```

Instructions and examples [here](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl)